# how to add a background color to my IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

if have the following IF statement:

```
=IF(R1=R3,"GreenBG","RedBG")
```

how can i add a background color using the IF statement (is it even possible)?

Comment: Use conditional formatting, you don't need VBA.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, conditional formatting is the better route. That being said, using a standard worksheet function inside the worksheet *cannot* alter the color.

For VBA, as tagged, it's pretty simple:

Option Explicit

```
Sub BGColoring()
    If Range("A1") = Range("A3") Then
        Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Else: Range("A1").Interior.Color = rbg(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the input Raystafarian. the comment on the function is what i was looking for.